# What are the differences between C# and Java (Android) when encrypting using RSA with PKCS1 padding?

Tags: java, c#, android, encryption, rsa

I'm encrypting a text using RSA with PKCS1 padding in Java (Android), that I have to send afterwards as part of the body in a webservice. The output of my Java code doesn't work, but if I do it in C#, technically the same algorithm, then it works fine.

This is the **C#** code that works fine:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var plainData = "plain_text";
        RSA publicKeyEncryptor = getRSAPublic(@"<public_key>");
        var plainBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainData);
        string encryptedPayload = System.Convert.ToBase64String(publicKeyEncryptor.Encrypt(plainBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1));
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedPayload);
    }

public static RSA getRSAPublic(string publicKey)
    {
        string publicKeyPem = $"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n{ publicKey }\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n";
        var pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(publicKeyPem));
        AsymmetricKeyParameter keyPairRaw = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)pemReader.ReadObject();
        RSAParameters rsaParams = DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)keyPairRaw);
        RSA rsaObj = System.Security.Cryptography.RSA.Create();
        rsaObj.ImportParameters(rsaParams);
        return rsaObj;
    }
```

When I try to convert it to **Java** (Android), this is the code I came up with, but it doesn't generate a valid output:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String stringToEncrypt = "plain_text";
    String publicKey = "<public_key>";
    System.out.println(encrypt(stringToEncrypt, publicKey))
}

public String encrypt(String plain, String publicKey) {
    try {
        byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decode(publicKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        PublicKey rsaPublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaPublicKey);
        byte[] plainTextBytes = plain.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        return Base64.encodeToString(encryptedBytes, Base64.NO_WRAP));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

What can be different?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be "RSA/`CBC`/PKCS1Padding"

Comment: That algorithm does not exist, I get: `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: No provider found for RSA/CBC/PKCS1Padding`
I tried also with `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` or `RSA/NONE/PKCS1Padding` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you using BouncyCastle? is this android?

Comment: Yes, this is Android. I tried using BouncyCastle provider by requesting the Cipher with `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC");`, but same results.

Comment: Sorry, afraid i can't help with that, Android is quite painful in many ways with crypto.. try higher version of OS, and on a real device

Comment: @zaitsman I made a test with Java 1.8 and the outcome is the same, so it doesn't seem to be related with Android

Comment: When you ask a question about why something doesn't work the way you expect it to, always include detailed information about what it currently does and why you are dissatisfied. Never say "it doesn't work" without providing details. For example, if it throws an exception provide the full stack trace of the exception. If the output doesn't produce the desired effect, state what effect is produced. Also, include sample inputs and outputs that illustrate the problem. These steps will make for a good question that has a better chance of being answered.

Comment: @zaitsman RSA is inteded to work only as ECB mode. For other modes (encrypting longer source data) hybrid encryption is needed

Comment: `Java code doesn't work` - could you be more specific? (btw, why are you using Base64.NO_WRAP? Then the Base64 output is formally not valid)

Comment: @JamesKPolk The output looks the same (at least format wise). The problem is that the back-end is not able to decrypt the value generated with the Android code, but it is able to decrypt the value generated with the C# code.

Comment: @gusto2 We tried also using Base64 library of Java (instead Android), but it doesn't seem to affect.

Comment: "...Not able to decrypt..." well, what happens when it tries? Error message, exception, bad result... what?

Comment: I'd really guess you either use different public key or the issue is with the Base64 encoding (the NOWRAP parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both codes are right. You can encrypt data in same way with Java version and C# version. If one of them is working and another one is failing, probably you are using an incorrect public key (copy/paste error, some different bytes, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Both the Java and the C# program produce *compatible* output. Compatible, but not identical, because the output is supposed to be different every time. PKCS1 padding includes a random component for security reasons. Thus, if you were expecting identical output your expectations were wrong. Identical output would be a clue that something was wrong, the output is supposed to be different every time.

[RFC 8017, section 7.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2.1) explains in detail what is happening. In particular, step 2a says:

> Generate an octet string PS of length k - mLen - 3
> consisting of pseudo-randomly generated nonzero octets.
> The length of PS will be at least eight octets.

Just to verify their compatibility, I made up small C# and Java programs based on your code and found that each could decrypt the other's output and get the correct result.